# KnockoutJS Populate observableArray using TypeScript

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js, typescript

How can I populate an observableArray (KnockoutJS) using TypeScript? I have a class as my ViewModel.

Without TypeScript I would load the data using `$.getJSON();` and map it.

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.list_data = ko.observableArray([]);

    $.getJSON('/Home/Get', function (data) {
        var mapped = $.map(data, function (obj) { return new AClass(obj); });
        self.list_data(mapped);
    });
}
```

This is my class so far, I am loading the data in the constructor and get the JSON data array. I have tried to map it as well but no luck.

How do I store/map it in the `list_data = ko.observableArray([]);` in the TypeScript class?

```
class MyViewModel {
    constructor() {
        $.getJSON('/Home/Get', function (data) {
            alert(data);
        });
    }

    list_data = ko.observableArray([]);
}
```

Thanks

**EDIT:**

Here is the data from the server:

```
[{ "Product": "102289", "ArtworkId": 19431, "IsDownloaded": 1 },
    { "Product": "272203", "ArtworkId": 19423, "IsDownloaded": 1 },
    { "Product": "272222", "ArtworkId": 20306, "IsDownloaded": 1 },
    { "Product": "332245", "ArtworkId": 19430, "IsDownloaded": 1 },
    { "Product": "382277", "ArtworkId": 19424, "IsDownloaded": 0 },
    { "Product": "382256", "ArtworkId": 19425, "IsDownloaded": 1 },
    { "Product": "392272", "ArtworkId": 19416, "IsDownloaded": 1 },
    { "Product": "422242", "ArtworkId": 19422, "IsDownloaded": 1 },
    { "Product": "452295", "ArtworkId": 19414, "IsDownloaded": 0 },
    { "Product": "452219", "ArtworkId": 19421, "IsDownloaded": 0 },
    { "Product": "452214", "ArtworkId": 19413, "IsDownloaded": 0 },
    { "Product": "452223", "ArtworkId": 19415, "IsDownloaded": 1 },
    { "Product": "632204", "ArtworkId": 20051, "IsDownloaded": 1 },
    { "Product": "632238", "ArtworkId": 19432, "IsDownloaded": 1 },
    { "Product": "632295", "ArtworkId": 19419, "IsDownloaded": 1 },
    { "Product": "712220", "ArtworkId": 19417, "IsDownloaded": 1 },
    { "Product": "722240", "ArtworkId": 19433, "IsDownloaded": 1 },
    { "Product": "762258", "ArtworkId": 20273, "IsDownloaded": 0 },
    { "Product": "762278", "ArtworkId": 20274, "IsDownloaded": 1 },
    { "Product": "792297", "ArtworkId": 19418, "IsDownloaded": 1 },
    { "Product": "812202", "ArtworkId": 19429, "IsDownloaded": 0 },
    { "Product": "862280", "ArtworkId": 19420, "IsDownloaded": 1 }]
```

Comment: can you update the question with the data that you are getting from server ?

Comment: @Silly Volley, Added the data

Comment: well mapping is working fine as expected check console . sample here http://jsfiddle.net/eww5dn8q/3/ .

Comment: @super cool, yes that's the way I do it. I am not able to map it in the TypeScript class though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how it could look like in TypeScript:

```
class MyViewModel {
    list_data = ko.observableArray([]);
    constructor() {

        $.getJSON('/Home/Get', data => {
            var mapped = $.map(data, obj => new AClass(obj));
            this.list_data(mapped);
        });
    }
}
```

[This will compile into](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=class%20MyViewModel%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20list_data%20%3D%20ko.observableArray(%5B%5D)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%24.getJSON('%2FHome%2FGet'%2C%20data%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20mapped%20%3D%20%24.map(data%2C%20obj%20%3D%3E%20new%20AClass(obj))%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.list_data(mapped)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D):

```
var MyViewModel = (function () {
    function MyViewModel() {
        var _this = this;
        this.list_data = ko.observableArray([]);
        $.getJSON('/Home/Get', function (data) {
            var mapped = $.map(data, function (obj) { return new AClass(obj); });
            _this.list_data(mapped);
        });
    }
    return MyViewModel;
})();
```

Comment: How come `this` doesn't refer to the XHR object as it would in JavaScript? `$.getJSON('path.json', function() { console.log(this); // xhr object })` But rater using the instance: `var _this = this; $.getJSON('path.json', function() { console.log(_this); // instance of MyViewModel })`

Comment: Defining a function in the lambda notation will make sure `this` will point to the class. See the [TypeScript handbook](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#functions-lambdas-and-using-39this39)

Comment: So using lambda notation preserves the context (`this`)?

Comment: It will declare a `_this` outside of the scope, then use that variable when using `this` inside the lambda function. [See this sample](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=class%20MyViewModel%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0A%09%09%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%09normalFunction()%20%7B%0A%09%09console.log(this)%3B%0A%09%7D%0A%09lambdaFunction%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%09%09console.log(this)%3B%0A%09%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Avar%20normalFunction%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%09console.log(this)%3B%0A%7D%3B%0Avar%20lambaFunction%20%3D%20function%20()%20%7B%0A%09console.log(this)%3B%0A%7D%3B).

Comment: That's awesome thank you so much, i just had to `JSON.parse(data);` for it to work.

Comment: @Sander If you send `content-type: application/json; utf-8` in the service response header jQuery should parse the array (`data`) for you.